# PHP, Match line, and return value

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have multiple lines like this in a file:

```
Platform
  value:  router
Native VLAN
  value:  00 01
```

How can I use PHP to find 'Platform' and return the value 'router'

Currently I am trying the following:

```
$file = /path/to/file
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$value.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
   echo "Found Data:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else{
   echo "No Data to look over";
}
```

Comment: If the file follows a specific format already you should use a parser. IE, is it a .yml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heres another simple solution

```
<?php
  $file = 'data.txt';
  $contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  $find = 'Platform';
  if (false !== $key = array_search($find, $contents)) {
      echo 'FOUND: '.$find."<br>VALUE: ".$contents[$key+1];
  } else {
      echo "No match found";
  }
?>
```

returns

[image]

Comment: No worries mate, just mark your question as 'Answered'

Comment: Thanks! Just couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: @netpihelper You're welcome and *Welcome  to Stack* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really simple solution with explode.
Hope it helps.

```
function getValue($needle, $string){

    $array = explode("\n", $string);

    $i = 0;
    $nextIsReturn = false;

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if($i%2 == 0){
            if($value == $needle){
                $nextIsReturn = true;
            }
        }else{
            // It's a value
            $line = explode(':', $value);
            if($nextIsReturn){
                return $line[1];
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return null;
}

$test = 'Platform
          value:  router
        Native VLAN
          value:  00 01 ';

echo getValue('Platform', $test);
```

If the trailing spaces are a problem for you, you can use `trim` function.